# Is it possible to use Protocol Buffers natively for message passing between a Go web service and an Android app?

Tags: json, android-development, protobuf

I want to connect an Android app to a Go web service (I have a small social network in mind) and would like to pass data to and from the web service using Protocol Buffers, since it recently seems to have native support in both Android and Golang.

Is this possible or even advisable? Or should I stick to JSON?

Comment: What advantages do Protocol Buffers provide?

Comment: As far as I know, speed and compactness. At the moment, it seems like a choice between JSON and Protocol Buffers, and if Google have seen fit to implement Protocol Buffers natively in Android then there must be some benefit to developers.

Comment: So the answer to your question is "do you need the speed and compactness?"